# Facebook SDK post a story without permission in Unity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, soomla

I'm using Unity as my engine and connection the Facebook in my game, I want to add a feature that the user can post a story regarding the game.

I tried it with Soomla SDK, the "SoomlaProfile.UploadCurrentScreenShot" but the facebook guys decline my app permissions review saying that I cannot fill user textfield and the user should write his own text to publish.

I tried to use the embeded FB API "FB.Feed" but its asking after login to manually aprove the post permission even when it should be aprroved because it in the embbeded facebook dialog

Can this be done in any other way?

Comment: Is this the same question as you asked http://answers.soom.la/t/solved-facebook-integration-post-a-status/2171 Are you still looking for an answer or did you get it answered on the other forum?

Comment: The FB.Feed method should just trigger the Feed dialog to trigger. If the User is not logged into Facebook then they have to be logged in in order to publish the message, there is no way around this. Can you be a little bit more clear on " asking after login to manually aprove the post permission even when it should be aprroved because it in the embbeded facebook dialog"